# External drive seagate not working in Mojave OS

Tags: mojave

Recently I have upgraded the OS to mojave, after the upgrade I see the write option is disabled for my hard drive Seagate. NTFS format is done for the hard drive. Any one here facing this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

macOS cannot write to NTFS-formatted drives without the aid of a third-party utility. If you were able to write to the drive before updating, I would suspect you had such a utility installed, such as Tuxera NTFS or Paragon NTFS, and it needs to be updated to support macOS Mojave.

Comment: I do have Tuxera NTFS, also updated but still not working :(

Comment: @ToKra After making sure Tuxera NTFS is re-enabled, have you rebooted your machine? That's an important step that the software doesn't mention explicitly.

Comment: Actually, This issue hapened when I update to Mojave, the I also did update Tuxera, but now when I attach any NTF, also ExFat its read only. I did opened also ticket on Tuxera. lets see how it goes.